# Spring Security returns 403 on any request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I created two users with ADMIN and USER roles, but every time I try to login server return 403.

WebSecurityConfig:

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**")
                .access("hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN','USER')")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .and().csrf().disable();
    }
```

my UserService which maps my users from db:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userDao.findByUserName(username);
        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.UserBuilder builder = null;
        if (user != null) {

            builder = org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.withUsername(username);
            builder.disabled(!user.isEnabled());
            builder.password(user.getPassword());
            String[] authorities = user.getUserRole()
                    .stream().map(a -> a.getRole()).toArray(String[]::new);

            builder.authorities(authorities);
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found.");
        }
        return builder.build();
    }
```

csrf is disabled. I also use hasAnyUthority* method so I don't need ROLE_ prefix.
I use spring security 5

My login.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <h1>Login</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="alert alert-error" th:if="${error != null}">
        <div>
            <strong>Okay, Houston, we've had a problem here.</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-error" th:if="${logout != null}">
        <div>
            <strong>Okay, Houston, you're logged out successfully .</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" th:action="@{/login}" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Login</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-prepend">
                        <span class="add-on">@</span>
                        <input id="loginField" name="username" class="span3" type="text"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Password</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input id="passwordField" name="password" class="span3" type="password"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button id="loginButton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

I did everything as in example projects but it still doesn't want to log me in.

Comment: Show your login request with header and body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it will help someone so i will unswer my question.
I couldn't login becouse when i launch my program, i add some new users with not encrypted password. But spring security decrypts it anyways so that is why i couldn't login and got 403 repsonse. All i needed is to encrypt password before adding it into database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that `hasAnyAuthority(...)` will work without "ROLE_", try `.access("hasAnyRole('ADMIN','USER')")` or `.access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')")`.

Note that in `String[] authorities = user.getUserRole().stream().map(a -> a.getRole()).toArray(String[]::new);` you need in `a.getRole()` return with prefix `ROLE_` or the same what you will have in `hasAnyAuthority(...)`

For example if your `a.getRole()` will return `WHAT_EVER` than `hasAnyAuthority('WHAT_EVER)` should work, but `hasAnyRole('WHAT_EVER')` will expect that `a.getRole()` returns `ROLE_WHAT_EVER`

Comment: I have ADMIN with role 'ADMIN' and i use hasAnyAuthority. And it doesn't work. I know that hasAnyRole requiers ROLE_ADMIN. That is why i'm using hasAnyAuthority